# Why does strftime uppercase flag '^' not work?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, solaris

I have the following command `$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%d-%^b-%Y",localtime time-86400;')` which works on Red Hat Linux box, but not on a Sun Solaris 9 box.

Question 1: From what I read [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime), '^' is provided by glibc... is this correct?

Question 2: How do I find out why it's not working on the Solaris box? (And ultimately, how do I make it work?)

Comment: on mac os x it doesn't work... what do you need? man strftime doesn't show any piece of information on %^b

Comment: Works on the Linux box I tried, which would seem to indicate it is indeed up to whatever C library you have. Does `man 3 strftime` on your machine mention `^`?

Comment: on mac os x didn't appear. This is a workaround: perl -e 'use POSIX;print uc(strftime "%d-%b-%Y",localtime time-86400);'

Comment: This is a glibc extension, not part of the standard `strftime` specification.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I didn't realize I can do that and no, `^` is not a default flag. I think @Barmar confirms that it is a glibc extension

Comment: @MiguelPrz Duh! Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solaris is not *Linux*, Although it's Unix :-), System calls behave differently on different system, that's why you will see lots of #ifdef in C programs. You can compile [this C example of some time functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Functions-Example.html) on RedHat and Solaris and see the difference (convert %B to %^B and you will see that it will not print in uppercase).  The best solution is to use Perl's `uc` function.